# android webview doesn't render bullets properly

Tags: android, html, css, webview, outlook

I have an android email client. When it receives message from an outlook2011 in mac, I get a html data like this:

```
<html><head></head><body style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; "><ol><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li></ol></body></html>
```

And it shows the bullets properly. 
However, When I receive similar message from Outlook2013 in Windows, I get this html data:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
<!--
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
{margin:0in;
margin-bottom:.0001pt;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoListParagraph" style="text-indent:-.25in"><span style="">1.<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>one</p>
<p class="MsoListParagraph" style="text-indent:-.25in"><span style="">2.<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>two</p>
<p class="MsoListParagraph" style="text-indent:-.25in"><span style="">3.<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>three</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the webview in my app fails to render the bullets. It shows the text, but no bullets (numbered list).

The webview code is simple one.

```
private WebView  mMessageContentView;   //declaration
onCreate() {
mMessageContentView = whatever.getView(view, R.id.message_content);
//setup some zoom settings etc etc
mMessageContentView.setWebViewClient(someWebViewClientInstance);
}

private void setMessageHtml(String html) {
        if (html == null) {
            html = "";
        }
        if (mMessageContentView != null) {
            mMessageContentView.loadDataWithBaseURL("email://", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add in a stylesheet that defines `MsoListParagraph` and adds in your bullets.

Comment: Ok. I've got a bullet.css file with the definition. How do I add it to android webview so that this css file is used.

Comment: Simplest thing is to paste it into the document, alongside the rest of the CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following definition in style.css file in assets folder.

```
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:Cambria;}
p.MsoListParagraph, li.MsoListParagraph, div.MsoListParagraph
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:0in;
    margin-left:.5in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:Cambria;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-family:Helvetica;}
```

Then the following code edit to add the external css file.

```
private void setMessageHtml(String html) {
    if (html == null) {
        html = "";
    }
    if (mMessageContentView != null) {
        String htmlWithExternalCSS = addStyleDefinition(html);
        mMessageContentView.loadDataWithBaseURL("email://", htmlWithExternalCSS, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    }
}
private String addStyleDefinition(String html) {
    //insert at the end of <head> tag
    String headTag = "<head>";
    int index = html.indexOf(headTag);
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(html);
    buff.insert(index+headTag.length(), "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/style.css\" />";);
    return buff.toString();
}
```